# Can this business rule be enforced with an index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider following table:

```
ID, Name
==============
1, 'Name1'
1, 'Name1'
1, 'Name1'
2, 'Name2'
2, 'Name2'
```

Trying to insert (3, 'Name2') should fail because rows with the same Name value should always have the same ID value.

Can this be enforced with an index? I know it could be enforced with a trigger or constraint but both of these seem to be rather inelegant solutions.

Note that this question originates from real (more complex) business logic I reduced to this example to keep it simple.

Comment: Aside: There may be an opportunity for normalization here. If `Id`/`Name` pairs are always 1:1 then a separate table should be used to keep the pairs. (You assert that a `Name` always has a consistent `Id` associated, but that doesn't mean that the reverse is true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be enforced with an index.

Not an index on the base table though. You can create a view selecting and grouping on `ID, Name`.

Then create a unique index on that view with key column `Name`

---

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (
     ID   INT,
     Name VARCHAR(10)
  );

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT count_big(*) AS c,
         ID,
         Name
  FROM   dbo.YourTable
  GROUP  BY ID,
            Name

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX SomeIndex
  ON dbo.SomeView(Name)

GO
---SUCCEEDS
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES      (1,'Name1'),
            (1, 'Name1'),
            (1, 'Name1'),
            (2, 'Name2'),
            (2, 'Name2');

GO

---FAILS
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES      (3,
             'Name2');
```

Answer (score -1):

No it cannot be enforced with an index (on the base table).

It can be enforced with a CHECK constraint that calls a UDF.

It can also be enforced with a TRIGGER.